Change default 30 minute timeout in spark
How do I change the default 30 minute timeout in pyspark sessions? Are there any config files where I have to change?
I changed bin/spark/conf/spark-default.conf file's spark.network.timeout parameter. But it doesnot work.
Any help is much appreciated
